# IPython cell magic to convert cell to raw

Tags: python, formatting, ipython

I'm using Databricks to run my Python notebook, and often use `%md` to create cells containing section titles and annotations in my code (`Markdown` cells). Is there some way to create `Raw NBConvert` cells using a `%` command? `Raw NBConvert` is available in JupyterLab in drop down menu:

[image]

but not in Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

No, magics can't do that. The fact that a cell is a "raw" cell is independent of the kernel that execute code. There might be some hacks possible, but they will likely not be added in core Jupyter, and will probably break often.

If you are using Databrick, you want to contact support for that.